# Dynamically assign values to IDs based upon AJAX content

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have some javascript:

```
eval('var incomingJSON =' + ajaxObj.responseText);
for (p in incomingJSON.common) {
    document.getElementById(p).value = incomingJSON.common.p;
}
```

where ajaxObject.responseText is:

```
{
    "common": {
        "item1": "1",
        "item2": "2",
        "item3": "3",
        "item4": "4",
        "item5": "5" 
    }
}
```

The following line works:

```
document.getElementById(item1).value = incomingJSON.common.item1;
```

However, incomingJSON.common.p evaluates to "undefined".  The left side of the assign works fine.  What's the proper way to access the value in that object given the correct name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the bracket notation syntax:

```
document.getElementById(p).value = incomingJSON.common[p];
```

Comment: It's called bracket notation. Calling it array notation can lead to confusion, so please don't. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Member_Operators

Comment: I knew it was going to be easy.  Thanks.